# What are pit fields?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, tissue

I found this statement from my biology text book,

> "The sieve tube elements and the companion cells are connected by pit fields present between the common longitudinal walls".

Is the pit field same as Plasmodesmata ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pit vs plasmodesmata**

From [wikipedia > pit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit_(botany))

> Pits are thin portions of the cell wall that adjacent cells can communicate or exchange fluid through, utilizing plasmodesmata.

The definition of "pit" is therefore very related to the one of "plasmodesmata". From [wikipedia > plasmodesmata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmodesma)

> Plasmodesmata (singular: plasmodesma) are microscopic channels which traverse the cell walls of plant cells and some algal cells, enabling transport and communication between them.

I think the following quote (from [wikipedia > plasmodesmata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmodesma) again) will help you to distinguish pits from plasmodesma

> Primary plasmodesmata are formed when portions of the endoplasmic reticulum are trapped across the middle lamella as new cell wall is laid down between two newly divided plant cells and these eventually become the cytoplasmic connections between cells. Here the wall is not thickened further, and depressions or thin areas known as pits are formed in the walls. Pits normally pair up between adjacent cells. Plasmodesmata can also be inserted into existing cell walls between non-dividing cells (secondary plasmodesmata)

**Pit field**

A pit field however is just an area where there are plenty of pits! From [Merria-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pit%20field)

> [A pit field is] an area in the wall of a plant cell in which one or more pits develop

Answer (score 0):

Pit field is thin depression in primary cell wall whereas pits are depressions in secondary cell wall. For example Companion cells and sieve tube elements are living cells having primary walls. They are connected by pit fields. Note that pit fields are also characterised by presence of plasmodesmatal connection.

Comment: Welcome Mudasir, in addition to the advice in the answer banner, you should take our wonderful [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when for guidance. Enjoy the site.